# Improving select xml.value() performance, SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

SQL Server 2008 R2

I am using

```
select (xmlfield.value('data((/a/rvd)[1])'), 'nvarchar(max)')
```

to extract values from a column of type XML. It takes 20 minutes for 1 million rows.

Is there any way to improve this?

Comment: When you *store* that XML data, you could extract this value and store it separately (or use a computed column), and index that column.

Comment: Do you have any XML indexes?